# SQL how to format time containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, winforms

Please help.  Having a little bit of a problem here and need some help figuring it out.  I have a query that returns multiple rows and when I try to format the time to display as I would like I get the following message...

Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Here is the format I used when I get the error...

```
CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, 0, EntryTime)) / 3600 AS varchar(12)) + ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, 0, EntryTime)) / 60 % 60 AS varchar(2)), 2) + ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, 0, EntryTime)) % 60 AS varchar(2)), 2)
```

Which when I run it in in a query by itself I get the correct format that I would like...

```
Project Name     Total Time
AAA               0:00:19
BBB               0:00:04
CCC               6:00:06
DDD               16:05:52
```

But, I can't seem to figure out how to format the following query to display time in this manner...

```
SELECT ProjName AS 'Project Name', 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SUM(CASE WHEN Phone = 0 AND Research = 0 
                                     THEN (DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, EntryTime))  
                                END)) AS [Total Time No PMRE], 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SUM(CASE WHEN Phone = 1 AND Research = 0 
                                     THEN (DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, EntryTime))  
                                END)) AS [Total Time Phone], 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SUM(CASE WHEN Phone = 0 AND Research = 1 
                                     THEN (DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, EntryTime)) 
                                END)) AS [Total Time Research], 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, EntryTime)) ) AS 'Total Time'
FROM WorkTime
WHERE EntryTime IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ProjName
```

And get the following result...

```
Project Name  Total Time No PMRE  Total Time Phone  Total Time Research  Total Time
AAA           19                  NULL              NULL                 19
BBB           4                   NULL              NULL                 4
CCC           10800               7200              3606                 21606
DDD           57952               NULL              NULL                 57952
```

All of which are correct but I need help in figuring out how to format the time to display as hrs:mins:secs... Actually, I don't need the seconds, just hours and minutes but any advice, help, pointing in the right direction would be wonderful.  Thank you!

Comment: as long as time is below 24 hours you ca use: Declare @Seconds int=123  
Select Convert(Varchar(20),DateAdd(ss,@Seconds,0),108 )

Comment: Thanks for the advice Mark!  Unfortunately, there will be times that are over 24 hours.

Comment: You voted on the wrong post ;-), you would have to vote on @MarkBannister

Comment: Mark, You are my HERO! I had to make some minor changes, but got it to work. Thank You! I had to add, ([Project Name], [Total Time No PMRE], [Total Time Phone], [Total Time Research], [Total Time]) after with cte and before the as, and then remove the ProjName AS from the cte query. Once that was done it worked and worked how I needed it to. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
with cte as
(SELECT ProjName , 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Phone = 0 AND Research = 0 THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, EntryTime) END) AS [Total Time No PMRE], 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Phone = 1 AND Research = 0 THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, EntryTime) END) AS [Total Time Phone], 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Phone = 0 AND Research = 1 THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, EntryTime) END) AS [Total Time Research], 
        SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, EntryTime)) AS [Total Time]
 FROM WorkTime
 WHERE EntryTime IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY ProjName)
SELECT ProjName AS [Project Name], 
       CAST([Total Time No PMRE] / 3600 AS varchar(12)) + ':'
       + RIGHT('0' + CAST([Total Time No PMRE] / 60 % 60 AS varchar(2)), 2) + ':'
       + RIGHT('0' + CAST([Total Time No PMRE] % 60 AS varchar(2)), 2) AS [Total Time No PMRE], 
       CAST([Total Time Phone] / 3600 AS varchar(12)) + ':'
       + RIGHT('0' + CAST([Total Time Phone] / 60 % 60 AS varchar(2)), 2) + ':'
       + RIGHT('0' + CAST([Total Time Phone] % 60 AS varchar(2)), 2) AS [Total Time Phone], 
       CAST([Total Time Research] / 3600 AS varchar(12)) + ':'
       + RIGHT('0' + CAST([Total Time Research] / 60 % 60 AS varchar(2)), 2) + ':'
       + RIGHT('0' + CAST([Total Time Research] % 60 AS varchar(2)), 2) AS [Total Time Research], 
       CAST([Total Time] / 3600 AS varchar(12)) + ':'
       + RIGHT('0' + CAST([Total Time] / 60 % 60 AS varchar(2)), 2) + ':'
       + RIGHT('0' + CAST([Total Time] % 60 AS varchar(2)), 2) AS [Total Time]
FROM cte
```